# How to register USPS shipping method account in magento2.4.5

Tags: magento2

How to register USPS shipping method account in magento2. If we use https://registration.shippingapis.com/ get the username and password from mail while using this details working in magento2 but unable to create shipping label in magneto admin shipment. Can one use please help me?

We need how to create shipping label in magento2